# Can I hold two work visa in two different countries at the same time?

Tags: working-visas, working

Currently am working in a country with a valid work visa, is it okay to have another work visa in another country?

Comment: Why would it not be okay?

Comment: The answer will depend upon the visa rules in each of the two countries.

Comment: Which countries?

Comment: Are you asking about having a literal visa (a sticker in your passport), or actually holding multiple jobs in multiple contries?

Comment: @Traveller Currently am working in Philippines, but i have a job offer in Belgium.

Comment: Typically employers are required to *cancel* a work visa when they wish to terminate the employment of a foreign national (e.g., at the expiry of the employment contract, or on resignation of the employee). So I suspect the answer is likely to be that you can *apply* for another work visa during the validity of an existing work visa, but you cannot *hold* two work visas simultaneously as you will no longer fulfil the eligibility criteria for the original visa if you take up employment elsewhere.

Comment: @Traveller am holding work visa in Philippines, now i have job offer in Belgium. My previous employer didnt cancel my last visa yet. Without cancelling the last one, is it okay to cross the emigration?  Do i need to cancel it first or its okay? Am confused about to face the emigration.

Comment: According to https://www.duranschulze.com/getting-an-emigration-clearance-certificate/ you need an Emigration Clearance Certificate. I would not recommend trying to leave without following the correct procedure, whatever that is. However, that is *not* the question you posted